# Transforming a dataframe by "multiplying" a column's elements by the names of the other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

An example is below. How can I transform a dataframe `df` with column `names` to the form of `df.transformed` below?

```
> df <- data.frame("names" = c("y1", "y2"), "x1" = 1:2, "x2" = 4:5)
> df
  names x1 x2
1    y1  1  4
2    y2  2  5


> df.transformed <- data.frame("y1x1" = 1, "y1x2" =4, "y2x1" = 2, "y2x2" = 5)
> df.transformed
  y1x1 y1x2 y2x1 y2x2
1    1    4    2    5
```

Comment: Does `unlist(df[-1])` suffice?

Comment: No the names in totality are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line with the new `tidyr::pivot_wider`. Setting multiple columns for values means names will get pasted together for assignment.

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, names_from = names, values_from = c(x1, x2), names_sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    x1y1  x1y2  x2y1  x2y2
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2     4     5
```

However, the column names ("x1", "x2") come first. If you need to swap the "x" and "y" components of the names, you can do regex replacement with `dplyr::rename_all`.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = c(x1, x2), names_sep = "") %>%
  dplyr::rename_all(gsub, pattern = "(x\\d+)(y\\d+)", replacement = "\\2\\1")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    y1x1  y2x1  y1x2  y2x2
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2     4     5
```

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

```
require(data.table); setDT(df)

dt = melt(df, id.vars = 'names')[, col := paste0(variable, names)]
out = dt$value; names(out) = dt$col
```

**Result**

```
> data.frame(t(out))

x1y1 x1y2 x2y1 x2y2 
   1    2    4    5
```

Comment: The output is not what the OP expects.

Comment: Eh, technically you are right, however I doubt that the column ordering (xnyn or ynxn) matters strongly in this particular context.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in base R. This should work for any data frame size. The idea is combine `Reduce` with `outer` to build the data frame column names.

```
df <- data.frame("names" = c("y1", "y2"), "x1" = 1:2, "x2" = 4:5)

df_names <- outer(df[,1], names(df[,-1]), paste0)
df.transformed <- as.data.frame(matrix(,ncol = nrow(df)*ncol(df[,-1]), nrow = 0))
names(df.transformed) <- Reduce(`c`,t(df_names))
df.transformed[1,] <- Reduce(`c`,t(df[-1]))
```

**Output**

```
#  y1x1 y1x2 y2x1 y2x2
#    1    4    2    5
```